How to use Enviornment Variables with Azure web apps NextJS
Im at the end of my rope here, i've tried everything i can think of, researched etc. I have a nextjs 14 app, i've deployed to azure web apps via github worfklows, there are several enviornment variables i need in the application, In development on my machine they work perfectly, i set my env in my .env file, and in next.config i reference those variables with process.env.VAR_NAME and it works, those variables that i set in the .env are available in my application, even if i build and run npm run start command, they are still available, however when in production on azure, these variables are not available, and i cant figure out how to set them properly, the only time the variables work is if i set them explicitly in next.config, it refuses to read the Enviornment variables from azure's config files..
I've tried a number of things to get this to work, such as running a small script to create a .env.production file in the startup commands, but i've not had any luck..

add your environment variables under "Application settings" (e.g., VAR_NAME = your_value) in the environment variables section of your Azure Web App.

Did that, they still arent available to the application, and before you ask.. yes they are spelled correctly..

if possible, please share your next.config file

currently it just has one variable (ill add others when i figure this out): that variable is: NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL, in my .env file locally its set correctly, in azure its set the same way.. even if i try to reference it as process.env.API_URL with a var named appropriately, its not available to nextjs

ok will try and let you know

@SirraSneha, check my answer, i think i found the solution..

Ok, so i have a solution to my issue:
The reason that it works in development and not production is that in my local enviornment .env is accessible with variables that are needed, so once i build the project, those are injected. However, using github workflows, the .env variables are not available at build time in the nextjs project, because there is no .env file in my repository the project is built and then sent to azure for deployment, and since the .env is only available on azure it doesnt know about them.
I tried running the build command through the startup actions however this doesnt work, it throws an error that it cant find next
so the solution to my issue was to find a way to get these variables available at build in github here is the process i followed so far:
1. Add Secrets to GitHub
I added the required environment variables as GitHub Secrets in the repository:
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
To add them:
Go to your repository on GitHub.
Navigate to Settings > Secrets and variables > Actions > New repository secret.
Add your variables with their values.
2. Modify the GitHub Actions Workflow
I updated my GitHub Actions workflow to pass these secrets as environment variables during the build step. Here's what my workflow file looks like:
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build Next.js App
        run: npm run build
        env:
          NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL }}  }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: "my-app-name"
          slot-name: "production"


3. Update next.config.js
I ensured my next.config.js file was properly configured to use these environment variables:
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL, 
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;


4. Azure Application Settings for Runtime Variables
In addition to GitHub Secrets for build-time variables, I added the same environment variables to Azure Application Settings. This ensures the variables are available at runtime for server-side code.
5. Finally
With these changes:
The build process now uses GitHub Secrets to inject the environment variables during npm run build.
The variables are accessible in the app, both client-side and server-side, in production.
